# How to read a text file saved as hex.txt which has hex values in Swift?

Tags: swift, file, utf-8, hex

I have the hexadecimal representation of a Data in text file in Swift.

Here is the sample Data:
132778507 140197074 140197084 140197094 140197317|uóˇ 140197319 140197325|uóˇ 140197329 140197331 140197335 141863276 142931011 152417365|uóˇ

Eventually I'd want to read it like this:

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "hex", ofType: "txt") {
        do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
            print(contents)

            let origData = Data(contents.utf8)

             catch  {
            } 

Here is the debug area:
(lldb) po String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "The file “hex.txt” couldn’t 
be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be 
determined." UserInfo=.
```

Comment: Is hex.txt a binary file?

Comment: And what is that supposed to be? That's not hex representation. From where did you get "132778507 140197074" ? How did you get that?